# Consul - service detection Microservice/Domain architecture

Tags: c#, rest, microservices, consul

I'm having a Microservice (MS)/Doamin (D) architecture where each MS/D service has its own rest api. I have been looking into using Consul for service detection but I cant figure out how to use it because. I have followed the documentation but it cant find how to use Consul in MS/D architecture where all MS/D has more than one rest endpoint...

In documentation it feels like you are registrating a plain "service host" you are not registering a service endpoint like "mydomain.com:8080/api// you are just registering "mydomain.com:8080/ i.e the host running the service. It feels like I have missed something but I really cant figure out how to register rest-api urls using Consul. I'm using Consul.NET (https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet) and my setup for registering a Microservice is:

```
var client = GetServiceClient();
var httpCheck = new AgentServiceCheck()
{
  DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
  Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
  HTTP = $"http://{host}:{microservicePort.ToString()}/healthcheck/"
};

var agentReg = new AgentServiceRegistration()
{
  Checks = new[] { httpCheck },
  Address = <serviceIp>,
  ID = microServiceUniqueIdentifier,
  Name = <servicename>,
  Port = microservicePort,
};
```

How can I register all rest api endpoints for 1 Microservice like:

```
<microservice1>/api/<entity>/<api-service1> with <servicename> ms1_service1 
<microservice1>/api/<entity>/<api-service2> with <servicename> ms1_service2 
<microservice1>/api/<entity>/<api-service3> with <servicename> m1s_service3
```

so another MS/D service can ask Consul get me rest-endpoint for ms1_service3

If I cant do this the "know how" of how service endpoint look like must be in calling system which feels wrong so... It feels like I have missed some fundamental things here.

I have also been looking into usin KV to store rest-api-endpoints but because its key value you only can register 1 service per key value so if I have 10 MS of one kind only 1 kan be stored in current "key" value.

Would be very happy if someone could help me to explain best practice for how to use Consul in combination with MS/D-rest endpoints

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the [Microphone](https://github.com/rogeralsing/Microphone) library in C#, which is easy to configure and use.

It also seems that you can register differents services located on the same machines without problem with this library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I dont see how this framework could helo because.... As not using it it is upp to the calling client to now how the rest url looks like. In example in documentation of Microphone it looks like: MakeSomeCall("/api/orders",instance.ServiceAddress, I would like to get the hole rest url for current instance not only the host-url of current service

Comment: Or are you saying that when doing: Cluster.RegisterService(new Uri($"http://localhost/api/someaction"), provider, "orders_someaction", "v1", logger); I can set the url to my action url?